# How to solve/transform system of equations (linear algebra/R)

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose I have the following system of equations in matrix form, how to I get the expected outputs?

Example 1:

```
#2x+2y+2z
#0x+0y+1z
mat1 <- matrix(c(2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1), 2, byrow = TRUE)

#want to get x+y+z
u1 <- matrix(c(1,1,1), 1, byrow=TRUE)

Expected output:
exp1 <- matrix(c(0.5,0), 2, byrow=TRUE)
```

Example 2:

```
#1x+1y+1z
#0x+1y+0z
mat2 <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), 2, byrow = TRUE)

#want to get x+z
u1 <- matrix(c(1,0,1), 1, byrow=TRUE)

Expected output:
exp1 <- matrix(c(1,-1), 2, byrow=TRUE)
```

I try to use ginv (i.e. `mat1 %*% MASS::ginv(u1)`), which does not work. Maybe I am using it incorreclty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing the errors in the inputs in the question we can use `ginv` or `lm` .  In the cases shown there is a solution but it would be possible to have similar problems with no solution so it is recommended, in general, to check the answer.

```
library(MASS)

mat1 <- matrix(c(2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1), 2, byrow = TRUE)
u1 <- matrix(c(1,1,1), 1)

t(u1 %*% ginv(mat1))
##              [,1]
## [1,] 5.000000e-01
## [2,] 2.220446e-16

matrix(coef(lm(t(u1) ~ t(mat1) + 0)))
##      [,1]
## [1,]  0.5
## [2,]  0.0


mat2 <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), 2, byrow = TRUE)
u2 <- matrix(c(1,0,1), 1)

t(u2 %*% ginv(mat2))
##      [,1]
## [1,]    1
## [2,]   -1

matrix(coef(lm(t(u2) ~ t(mat2) + 0)))
##      [,1]
## [1,]    1
## [2,]   -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `solve` function

```
solve(tcrossprod(mat1), tcrossprod(mat1, u1))
     [,1]
[1,]  0.5
[2,]  0.0

solve(tcrossprod(mat2), tcrossprod(mat2, u2))
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]   -1
```